# your connection is not private

Tags: android, ssl

I have a web-site built using ASP.net and I have valid ssl certificate generated and renewed from GoDaddy.

When the users try to access the site using https://  on a PC it works fine, but if they try to use the same link on a tablet or phone (Android) they get the error:

Your connection is not private . Attackers might be trying to steal your information from  
The server could not prove that it is  its security certificate is not trusted by your device's operating system.

Is there a specific setting I need to add/change in my application to make it trusted by Android OS or is it something that Android users have to do on their devices?

I don't see this error with other secure sites I use on my phone or tablet, so I assume it is something I need to do in my app settings.

Anyone experience this?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Did you check if your Goddaddy's cert's CA public key is in the android browser's keystore. If it's not, then the browser won't trust anything signed by that CA, since it hasn't been told it's trustworthy.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem.
It seems the intermediate certificate was not installed on IIS.

Depending on OS and/or browser/PC security settings, some browsers complained that the site is not trusted because of that, but some other PCs didn't.

The solution was to remove the existing certificate, then install a new one using re-key option on GoDaddy web site. This solved the problem.

I am just posting the solution just in case someone runs into the same issue.